# Deploy JSON file with the app and access it on runtime

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, assets

Is there a way to add a JSON file to my Ionic project and deploy it with the app to my device and then access it on runtime? I thought about using the assets folder but then again how would I retrieve the content of the assets folder within Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Deploy JSON file with the app and access it on runtime

Options:

## Bundle it

If you import it e.g. `import x from './x.json'` it will get built as a part of your bundle. Supported by webpack / ts-loader out of the box.

## Load it

You can use `fetch` to load it at runtime e.g `fetch('/assets/x.json').then(x=>x.json()).then(loaded => /*use it */)`.